# What is the benefit if any, of nesting async calls (using async, setImmediate, Promises etc)

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async.js, event-loop

In NodeJs there are a lot of techniques/libraries which helps us create asynchronous work, e.g.  Node async library, Promises, using NodeJs standard calls (setImmediate/setTimeout/nextTick).

In relation to server side applications, Sometimes I run into code like this:

```
function doWork() {
    async.parallel([work1func, work2func],
    (err, result) => { doSomthingWithTheResult(); }
}

function work1func(cb) {
    doSomeStuff1();
    async.series([moreWork1, moreWork2…], cb);
}

function work2func(cb) {
    doSomeStuff2();
    async.series([moreWork3, moreWork4…], cb);
}
```

As you can see, within work1Func, work2Func there are also async inner-calls to other functions using async.series as well (could have been async.parallel or any other async mechanism).

**Q: Is there any benefit having nested async calls?** I am asking because if the top most call is async why making nested calls async as well if we are already running asynchronously.

Can someone please explain (maybe give an example), and also give some rules of thumbs here ? when should I nest async call within async call and when just a single async is suffice.

Comment: How would you write this without nested calls, without changing the behavior? `async.parallel` and `async.series` do different things - the former runs functions at the same time, the latter runs them one after the other.

Comment: I don't want to remove the nested calls into a single call. I just put in doubt the inner async call. an alternative would be doWork() calling work1func() (which will not do async call) but will call moreWork1() and afterwards moreWork2()

Answer (score 0):

It's not a question of benefit. If you have an outer task which is known to complete asynchronously, but which invokes an inner task which *also* completes asynchronously, both outer and inner tasks have to handle their asynchronicity independent of each other. If the inner task's asynchronicity is ignored, then the outer task might falsely complete before the inner has actually finished.

For an example: say you have a module that makes queries to multiple external services (APIs, databases, etc) and performs some operation to combine the results. Obviously the module completes its task asynchronously, because it depends on the other services; but each of those service calls completes asynchronously as well. Since the module operates on the results of these inner calls, it could not return the correct output if they were not also asynchronous.

Even if there were only one inner task, this module would still have to wait in order to process the results. Ignoring asynchronicity is only feasible when you don't care about the output at any stage.